# Inset shadow effect

Tags: css

How to make this inside shadow effect with CSS?

[image]

So far I got this http://jsfiddle.net/yX26J/. How to apply shadow only left and top?

Comment: This seems to work for Chrome: `-webkit-box-shadow: inset -1em -1em 2em #111;` looks like a hack though. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the offset of the shadow with:

```
div {
    width:80px; height:110px;
    background:#3183bd;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 1em 1em 1em -1em #111;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1em 1em 1em -1em #111;
    box-shadow: inset 1em 1em 1em -1em #111;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ga6cy/4/

Comment: I found this page while looking for a Cutout/Inset with Shadow effect in CSS. No left or right just from top to bottom. So Thanks @Vincent, your answer helped me to achieve what I was looking for with some minor adjustments: http://jsfiddle.net/ga6cy/93/

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use inset. It's supported in all the recent versions of all the browsers that support box-shadow:

```
div.box {
  box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 10px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 10px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 10px #000000;
}
```

This page cites the browser support:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-box-shadow

Answer (score -2):

I had this same issue the other day.

I'm pretty sure its not possible to define the 'top' 'left' 'bottom' 'right' which is a shame.